# Uploading and downloading data in the background on Android

Tags: android, background-process

I've had a look at:

http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#service

And it's not really clear if it will serve my purpose. It sounds like you can have it perform actions on another thread and it will alert the activity once it is complete.

But what happens if a user goes to a different activity (say, they click "back" and go to the previous screen) in the application while the data is still transferring in the other thread? Does the original activity still get updated? Does it automatically display that activity again when the task completes?

I don't want to start developing this feature if it's not possible to do what I want to do, so I was hoping someone here could confirm for me. Is it possible to have the activity update, even if the user has gone to another activity while the data is still transferring?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use an asynctask:

If you want to keep a user in a single activity while data is transferring you can display a non cancelable progressbar or dialog, or disable click events for any view that will change activities.

If you want to allow the user to keep using the app you could make a static boolean variable isUpdating. When the asynctask executes check if its true/false in the [on pre execute method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) of the asynctask to determine if you should continue running it or cancel it.  And in the [on post execute method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) set it back to false this way only one instance will run at a time.

When the asynctask runs, you want to make all your heavy computations, httpposts/gets and data changes, like updating a database or what ever file storage you use inside the [doinbackground method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29).  And all your changes to the UI in the [onprogressupdate method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29).

I also think theres a way to make async tasks synchronous depending on how you initialize them but can't remember exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use AsyncTasks: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> But what happens if a user goes to a different activity (say, they
>   click "back" and go to the previous screen) in the application while
>   the data is still transferring in the other thread? Does the original
>   activity still get updated? Does it automatically display that
>   activity again when the task completes?

This behavior depends on how you designed your activity. You can use the attribute launchMode on your activity definition on the manifest file to have only one instance of your activity, but be careful with that, becouse every time the activity instance is shown it is recreated (onCreate method is called). Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode